# Apply css rule only if previous div exists

Tags: html, css

If I have a `div-a` and `div-b`, is it possible to apply a css rule to a `div-b` only if `div-a` exists? or apply rule to div-a only if div-b exists? 
(without using jQuery).

```
<div class="box">
<div class="div-a>..</div>
<div class="div-b>..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It depends on how exactly `div_a` and `div_b` are related.

Comment: It's possible if `div-b` is a child of `div-a`. You would then do that: `div.a div.b {}`. May we know the purpose?

Comment: I added the example markup

Comment: If the html will be rendered you could check if `div-b` has to be rendered and in that case you add a css cls like `div-b-exists` to `div.box`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no. Unless `div-b` is a child or sibling of `div-a`.

For any descendant:

```
.div-a .div-b
```

For direct children:

```
.div-a > .div-b
```

For siblings:

```
.div-a ~ .div-b
```

For adjacent siblings:

```
.div-a + .div-b
```

See [child and sibling selectors](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

Note that these relations work one way only. In all cases I provided above, they are applied to div-b, but only if div-b is inside (child) or after (sibling) div-a. Given your mark-up, you could use the `sibling` or `adjacent sibling` combinator to style div-b, but there is no way to style div-a conditionally.

I think the best option is to add an extra class to the parent if it contains div-b. Then you could simply use the simple combined selector `.parent-class .div-a` to style it.